# show two objects at once

Tags: opengl, glfw

Well the origins of this questions lie there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820456/strange-behavior-in-application-using-glfw

But I decided to simplify question with less text data and pictures(Now I use triangles)

I've got two objects - both objects are using vbo. I initalize every object  using constructor and method `init`

```
Character::Character() {
glm::vec3 vert[] = {
    glm::vec3(-.5f, -.5f, 0.0f) ,
    glm::vec3(.5f, -.5f, 0.0f) ,
    glm::vec3(0.0f, .5f, 0.0f) 
};
vertices.insert(vertices.begin(), vert, vert + 3);
}

void Character::init() {
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Character::draw() {
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

In another class `glfwinitializer` I keep both objects in `std::vector<Character>`.  So in function `main` I create two objects and then `push_back` them into vector. 
Draw loop is simple - I iterate through `vector` and call `draw` method

```
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for(int i = 0; i < scene_items.size(); i++) {
        scene_items[i]->draw();
    }
    this->navigator();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Method `navigator` calculates new position of objects when objects are selected. In every method, where I update data of vector `vertices` I call method

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

For example(method `move_offset` is called in `navigator`)

```
void Character::move_offset(double x_offset, double y_offset) {
for(int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
    vertices[i].x += x_offset;
    vertices[i].y += y_offset;
}
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec3) * vertices.size(), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
};
```

But two triangles are not shown on the screen at the same time - when I select one object - another object disappears. When I click on `disappeared` triangle - it appears and another disappears. (There is also one triangle in the initial location but it cannot be moved)

Why? Is there problem with buffers?

**EDIT: PROJECT REPRODUCING PROBLEM WITH ADDITIONAL LIBS**

visual studio 2010 project (9 mb)
[project with libs](http://www.filedropper.com/project_1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the full source code in the linked project, but from what you have pasted here, you seem not to call `glBindBuffer()` in your `move_offset()` method - thus overwriting the buffer of whatever object was last bound (probably the last one drawn in your loop).